# How to add separator between elements in a warning message?

Tags: r

This question has most likely been answered many times already, but I do not seem to find an answer even after a vigorous search...

I want to create a warning message using a character vector. The elements within the vector should be separated by ", " and should not be repeated. Like this:

> Warning message: Entries This, that, this too, probably also that should be checked.

The function [`warning`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/warning.html) passes the message to [`cat`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cat.html) function, which makes it difficult for me to understand how should I use the `cat` inside `warning`:

```
entries2check <-c("This", "that", "this too", "probably also that")

cat("Entries", entries2check, "should be checked.", sep = ", ")  # works
# Entries, This, that, this too, probably also that, should be checked.

paste("Entries", entries2check, "should be checked.", collapse = ", ") # repeated
# [1] "Entries This should be checked., Entries that should be checked., Entries this too should be checked., Entries probably also that should be checked."

# no separator
warning("Entries ", entries2check, "should be checked.") 
# Warning message:
# Entries Thisthatthis tooprobably also thatshould be checked. 

# cat comes before "Warning message:"
warning(cat("Entries", entries2check, "should be checked.", sep = ", ")) 
# Entries, This, that, this too, probably also that, should be checked.Warning message:

# correct place, but repeated
warning(paste("Entries", entries2check, "should be checked.", sep = ", ")) 
# Warning message:
# Entries, This, should be checked.Entries, that, should be checked.Entries, this too, should be checked.Entries, probably also that, should be checked.
```

Comment: `warning("Entries ", paste(entries2check, collapse=", "), " should be checked.")`

Comment: `toString` is ideal for this since it's essentially `paste(entries2check, collapse = ", ")`: `warning("Entries ", toString(entries2check), "should be checked.")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing this once, you can just use something like:

```
warning("Entries ", paste(entries2check, collapse=", "), " should be checked.")
```

If you want to formalize it a little, you can do something like:

```
mywarn <- function(..., sep = " ", collapse = ", ",
                   call. = TRUE, immediate. = FALSE, noBreaks. = FALSE, domain = NULL) {
  warning(
    paste(sapply(list(...), paste, collapse = collapse),
          sep = sep),
    call. = call., immediate. = immediate., noBreaks. = noBreaks., domain = domain
  )
}

mywarn("Entries ", entries2check, " should be checked.")
# Warning in mywarn("Entries ", entries2check, " should be checked.") :
#   Entries This, that, this too, probably also that should be checked.

mywarn("Entries ", entries2check, " should be checked.", call. = FALSE)
# Warning: Entries This, that, this too, probably also that should be checked.
```

(I added the arguments of `paste` and of `warning` to provide some more flexibility/control.)